React Google Maps Marker Icon Not Updating Dynamically
I'm working on a delivery app using React and @react-google-maps/api. I have a map component that shows the location of a delivery worker with a custom icon. However, I've run into an issue where the marker's icon does not update dynamically when the delivery worker's status changes (e.g., from "delivering" to "delivered").
Here's the simplified version of my map component:
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';

const mapContainerStyle = {
  width: '800px',
  height: '600px',
};
const center = {
  lat: -34.397,
  lng: 150.644,
};
const deliveryWorkerIcon = "https://www.citypng.com/public/uploads/large/701751694974714k04h1qhze9qoibj5zsdeldgmudwiygsfhulvidozwie8c3x74fcxvb3skcj0yqfnr2xehmarxrjwct6xtqgpbryyi5giatccgmjb.png";

const MapComponent = () => {
  return (
    <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey="">
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
        center={center}
        zoom={10}
      >
        <Marker
          position={center}
          icon={{
            url: deliveryWorkerIcon,
            scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(50, 50),
          }}
        />
      </GoogleMap>
    </LoadScript>
  );
};

export default MapComponent;

The marker is supposed to change when the delivery worker's status updates, but the icon remains the same. I've tried to use useState to dynamically update the deliveryWorkerIcon URL based on the worker's status, but the marker does not re-render with the new icon.
How can I ensure the marker icon updates dynamically in response to state or prop changes in my component?

From the code snippet you provided, I can't see the sections that:

Determine how your application is notified when the delivery worker's status changes.
Handle updating the marker's icon in response to a status change.

To dynamically change the marker, you'll need a way to listen for status change and then update the icon accordingly. It would've been helpful if you included the portion of your code where you used useState so we can also check for any potential issues.
In my  case, using the same libary (@react-google-maps/api), I used a useEffect hook to dynamically update the marker icons based on expiration times (which I included as a property on my marker object: expirationTime). Inside the effect, I set up an interval to regularly check if any marker's expirationTime has passed. If so, the icon will then be updated to the customized one.
You can check the sample result here.
Below is my complete Map component for you to check. Keep in mind that the specifics of how you'll implement status change listeners will depend on your application setup, so consider this as a guide.
import React, { useState, useRef, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { GoogleMap, useLoadScript, Marker } from "@react-google-maps/api";

const mapContainerStyle = {
    width: "100wh",
    height: "100vh",
};

const center = {
    lat: -37.397,
    lng: 150.644,
};

export default function Map() {
    const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
        googleMapsApiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    });

    const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
    const mapRef = useRef();

    // Add a marker to the map at the clicked location
    const onMapClick = useCallback((event) => {
        setMarkers((current) => [
            ...current,
            {
                lat: event.latLng.lat(),
                lng: event.latLng.lng(),
                customIcon: 'https://www.citypng.com/public/uploads/large/701751694974714k04h1qhze9qoibj5zsdeldgmudwiygsfhulvidozwie8c3x74fcxvb3skcj0yqfnr2xehmarxrjwct6xtqgpbryyi5giatccgmjb.png',
                expirationTime: new Date(Date.now() + 5000), // Expire the default icon after 5 seconds
            }
        ]);
    }, []);

    const onLoad = useCallback((map) => {
        mapRef.current = map;
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            setMarkers((markers) => markers.map((marker) => {
                // If marker is expired, change its icon to the custom icon
                if (new Date() > marker.expirationTime) {
                    return { ...marker, icon: marker.customIcon };
                } else {
                    return marker;
                }
            }));
        }, 1000); // Checks if the expirationTime passes every 1 second

        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, []);

    if (loadError) return "Error loading maps";
    if (!isLoaded) return "Loading Maps";

    return (
        <GoogleMap
            mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
            zoom={8}
            center={center}
            onClick={onMapClick}
            onLoad={onLoad}
        >
            {markers.map((marker, index) => (
                <Marker
                    key={index}
                    position={{ lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lng }}
                    icon={{ url: marker.icon, scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(50, 50), }}
                />
            ))}
        </GoogleMap>
    );
}

